# Estimate the volume of a shape using the trapezoidal rule.

Tags: calculus

> A 100 foot tall tree trunk has a circular cross section at every height and its circumference is given by the following table. Estimate the volume of the tree using the trapezoidal rule. $$\begin{array}{|c|c|}
> \hline\text{height (feet)} & 0 & 20 & 40 & 60 & 80 & 100\\\hline\text{circumference (feet)}&25&22&18&13&8&1\\\hline
> \end{array}$$

The way I approached this problem is that the volume = delta(h) * C.

So then the volume is approximately 20/2(25 + 2(22) + 2(18) + 2(13) + 2(8) + 1) = 1480.
Is this the correct way to do this problem or do I need to do it differently.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your reasoning on why delta $h \times$ circumference (I don't think that sounds right). Instead, consider the integral you'd want to approximate with the trapezoid formula, namely, $\int_a^b A(h) dh$

Comment: If $C=2\pi r$, then $A=\pi r^2=\pi(\frac{C}{2\pi})^2=\frac{C^2}{4\pi}$.

Comment: @kekkonen Yeah I don't know where my mind was when I was first trying to figure this out. I now have the following areas that correspond to the given heights: 625/(4pi), 121/pi, 81/pi, 169/(4pi), 16/pi, 1/(4pi). So if I apply the trapezoidal rule to the areas, then do I get the the sum of 2 times those areas (except for the first and last ones) times 10 = 2155.75